# Why additional options for JSLint in Notepad++ are ignored?

Tags: plugins, notepad++, jslint

I Installed the JSLint plugin at Notepad++ with choosing JSLint in `Plugins/Plugin Manager`.

My `Additional options` at `Plugins/JSLint/JSLint Options` are ignored.
I added: `/* jslint nomen: true,  vars: true, plusplus: true */` in the Additional options field.

`var _this = this;` is still causing the Error `Unexpected dangling '_' in '_this'`

Some Options can be set by clicking on it. This works. Unfortunately not all options are available as a click option.

I also included in the `Predefined` field: `"$","window","document","Image"`. This is also ignored:
`var i = new Image();` => `'Image' was used before it was defined.`

#### How can I define additional options for JSLint in Notepad++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out:

Write only the options in the field `Plugins/JSLint/JSLint Options/Additional options`, without the starting `/*jslint` and ending `*/`.

Write the names in the field `Plugins/JSLint/JSLint Options/Predifined` without `"`.

Klick at `Assume a browser`, than only `$` is needed in the `Predifined` field for jQuery.

If options are used in the source code, space between `/*` and `jslint` is not allowed. Use `/*jslint` and NOT `/* jslint`.